# How to add multiple Login Page with NextAuth and Calling Specific API Routes

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm working on a project where I need to implement a multiple login page using NextAuth and call specific API routes based on the login route. I've been exploring NextAuth's features, but I haven't found a straightforward solution for this requirement.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

When a user signs in from the /owner/login
route, I want to call the /api/owner
route and navigate to another specific route upon successful authentication.

Similarly, if a user signs in from the /user/login
route, I want to call the /api/user
route and navigate to a different route upon successful authentication.

I've tried using the signIn
callback in NextAuth, but it seems to only allow me to pass the same API routes for all login scenarios.

If anyone has encountered a similar situation or has any ideas on how to approach this, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar situation as you, where I need to implement two different sign in pages. My client wants to display different branding on the pages depending on the type of user that's visiting the site. But otherwise, I'm using the same auth provider, and the user is differentiated by a role which is maintained with my auth provider.

I didn't see something that would allow me to specify different auth APIs after looking through the docs, but this is how I'm planning to approach this problem:

- Provide two different login pages with essentially the same form components, just different branding. After the user attempts to sign in and has valid credentials, both types of users be then directed to the same page.
- On this *next* page, I'm retrieving the session in server side props and inspecting it for what type of user this is. Based on the type of user, I'm then redirecting them to their appropriate destination.

```js
// snippet from my [...nextauth].js config file
export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET_KEY,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'login',
      name: 'Login',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'Enter Email'
        },
        password: {
          label: 'Password',
          type: 'password',
          placeholder: 'Enter Password'
        }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        let loginResult = await myAuthProvider.loginWithEmailPassword({
          password: credentials?.password,
          email: credentials?.email,
        });

        // The loginResult is going to be returned which will then be added to the session. We'll be able to use
        // this loginResult from the session to be able to verify the user's identity in followup requests to the
        // server.
        return loginResult?.data;
      }
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({
      token,
      user,
      account
    }) => {
      // See: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback

      if (user) {
        token.provider = account ? .provider;
        token.user = user.member;
      }

      return token;
    },
    session: ({
      session,
      token
    }) => {
      // See: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback

      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.provider = token.provider;
        session.token = token;
        session.user = token.user;
      }

      return session;
    }
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: Number(process.env.JWT_TIMEOUT)
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
  },
});
```

```js
// in my intermediate "post login" page
import {
  useSession,
  getSession,
  signIn,
  signOut
} from "next-auth/react"

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let session = await getSession(context);
  let destination = "/";

  switch (session.user.role) {
    case "owner":
      destination = "/owner/dashboard";
      break;
    case "user":
      destination = "/user/dashboard";
      break;
  }

  if (session) {
    // if the user is already signed in and they navigate here, redirect them back to their appropriate dashboard.
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: destination,
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

I'm rather new to Next.JS and there is maybe a more perfect solution, but I can attest that this implementation works for me.